# If there are no submenus with a class of in, add a class to the first one

Tags: jquery

This works if there is no `submenu` with a class of `in`, but on another page which has a submenu with a class `in` this script still runs.

```
$(".nav-submenu").not(".in").eq(0).addClass("in");
```

Comment: *"...but its also adding the class if a class of in"* Can you clarify?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker thanks I have tried to make it more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!$(".nav-submenu.in").length)
  $(".nav-submenu").eq(0).addClass("in");
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent to what the OP is looking for: *If there are no submenus with a class of in, add a class to the first one*. These  snippets just check to see if the first `.nav-submenu` has a class of `.in`.